Latter vs former: Why is "latter half/stages/part" common/acceptable but not "former half/stages/part"?
Why is it much more common/acceptable to speak of the latter half (of e.g. the 19th century, 2023, an event, a process) than to do the same for former half?
Similarly with latter stages/part former stages/part.

From Ngrams, it seems that the ratio of use of latter half/stages/part to former half/stages/part was around 2 to 4 in the early 1800s. But today this ratio is around 30 to 100:



What explains this decline?

In response to StuartF:


In 2022,

"latter half of the twentieth century" was more than 1000 times as common as "former half of the twentieth century";
"second half of the twentieth century" was slightly less common than "first half of the twentieth century".

Similar orders of magnitude for 19th and 18th centuries:





Because the latter stage / part / X always means the second stage / part / X, but the former stage / part / X would often refer to something that used to be a stage / part / X (but no longer is). You can't expect latter and former to represent "mirror images" of "symmetrical, divisible" entities like that.

@FumbleFingers: Are you claiming that people would confuse the former half of 19th century as referring to something that used to be a half of the 19th century?

@user182601 You don't seem to be searching for "former half of 19th century" just "former half" or "former part". "Former part", "former half", etc will have other meanings and hence occur more often in texts.

You need to compare like with like, and drill down into the results in individual texts, because it's entirely possible e.g. that google books has more results from or about the second half of a century than the first half or something else that may bias the results. You also need to compare other options like first half and second half, and other forms like early 19th century and late?

@StuartF: See my edit

Among other things, former and latter are just two things mentioned: 'I like bean and bacon soup, but I found this heavy on the former and light on the latter. Too many beans or not enough bacon, I'm not sure; but that's what I'm getting at…uh, more bacon! Yes, more of the latter, please.' Brevity is a big deal, and clarity.

What @StuartF said. Your simplistic charts aren't comparing like with like. Even searching for The former part of the... will give misleading results because of "false positive matches" such as The former part of the Soviet Union (used to refer to a region which was formerly, previously part of the Soviet Union). See this chart showing that "relatively unambiguous" The former half of the... never had any currency anyway.
